# Disabling Keyboard Wakeup for Ubuntu 10.04 on Acer 1810TZ

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, acer-aspire, suspend

My Acer Aspire 1810TZ laptop suspends fine but wakes up on any slight key-press. I would like to disable this behaviour. I read that it involves disabling something in the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` but SLPB does not seem to be listed at all.

```
root@1810TZ:/etc# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
UHC0      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
UHC1      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.1
UHC2      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.2
UHCR      S3     disabled  
EHC1      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.7
UHC3      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
UHC4      S3     disabled  
UHC5      S3     disabled  
EHC2      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.7
EXP1      S4     disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4     disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
EXP2      S4     disabled  
PXSX      S4     disabled  
EXP3      S4     disabled  
PXSX      S4     disabled  
EXP4      S4     disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4     disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
EXP5      S4     disabled  
PXSX      S4     disabled  
EXP6      S4     disabled  
PXSX      S4     disabled
```

However, the relevant bits seem to be detected from dmesg.

```
[    0.357628] ACPI: AC Adapter [ACAD] (on-line)
[    0.357749] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.357754] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.357817] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    0.359319] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    0.359390] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
[    0.359394] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    0.359475] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    0.359479] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
```

Not quite sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the bios for wakeup events?   Generally the OS is sleeping and non-responsive at this point, so the bios/firmware would be handling the sensing of the wakeup stimulus.  Several of my systems have "wake on mouse/kb", "wake on lan" ... stuff like that.